# How to read a cookie on the client side security

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am developing my server side code using C# ASP.net. And my client is Javascript running on browser. And the client makes a request to server using https.
My question is if the server send a cookie in the client, does the client only can read the value of the cookie when it only has the same certificate?

Comment: The client can read the cookie if httpOnly flag is false  Https ensures the cookie cant be eavesdropped.  The secure flag means the cookie is only available over Https too.

Comment: Thanks. when you said "The secure flag means the cookie is only available over Https too" does that mean the client can't read the cookie value back in that case?

Comment: 1) httpOnly - cant be read via JS 
2) secure - only available over Https.
From memory though these arent flawless ways to be secure cookies though